# Poner una confirmación antes de eliminar un registro

Tags: php

Quiero eliminar un libro, con el numero de referencia de mi biblioteca, aunque antes quiero que me dé un aviso si quiero borrarlo o cancelar.

Lo que tengo hecho ahora en php es que me borre directamente el registro sin preguntar.

En la pagina admin.php hice este botón eliminar.

```
echo "<div class='or'></div>";    
echo '<a class="ui mini red button" href="eliminarlibros.php?numero='.$row['numero'].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </i>Eliminar</a>';
             echo "</div>"; 

en la pagina eliminar.php
           $numero = $_GET['numero'];
                    $coneccion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234");
                    mysqli_select_db($coneccion , "biblioteca");

                $consulta = "SELECT count(*) FROM prestados where ReferenciaLibro = '$numero' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $consulta);
                mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if($row[0] == 0)
                {
                    $req = "SELECT count(*) FROM libros where numero = $numero";
                    $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $req);
                    /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */           
                    $Eliminar = "delete from libros where numero = $numero ";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminar);
                    /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */            
                    $Eliminarapa = "delete from apa where numero = $numero ";
                    $resultadoapa = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminarapa);
                    /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */             
                    $Eliminarhardvard = "delete from hardvard where numero = $numero ";
                    $resultadohardvard = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminarhardvard);
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("se elimino el libro correctamente");'
        . 'window.location.href="admin.php";'
                . '</script>';
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

---

mi admin.php

```
       <?php
          $consulta = "select * from libros";
          $titulo = 'titulo';
          $numero = 'numero';
          $autor = 'autor';
          $ejemplares = 'ejemplares';
          $reservados = 'reservados';
          $prestados = 'prestados';
         /* $fecha = 'fechadevolucion';*/
          $apa = 'apa';
          $hardvard = 'hardvard';
          $result = mysqli_query( $coneccion, $consulta);
    echo "<table class='responsive-table table table-hover table-bordered'>
          <tr>
              <th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> REFERENCIA       </th>
              <th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> TITULO           </th>
              <th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> AUTOR            </th>
              <th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> EJEMPLARES       </th>
              <th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> RESERVADOS      </th>
              <th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> PRESTADOS      </th>
              <th  class ='bg-info' scope = 'col' colspan ='2'> OPCIONES      </th>

          </tr>";
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
              echo "<tr>";

             echo "<td>".$row[$numero]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row[$titulo]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row[$autor]."</td>"; 
             echo "<td>".$row[$ejemplares]."</td>"; 
             echo "<td>".$row[$reservados]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row[$prestados]."</td>";
             echo '<td width=250>';
             echo "<div class='ui mini buttons'>";
             echo '<a class="ui mini positive button" href="modificarlibros.php?numero='.$row['numero'].'"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Editar</a>';
             echo "<div class='or'></div>";    
             echo '<a class="ui mini red button" href="eliminarlibros.php?numero='.$row['numero'].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </i>Eliminar</a>';
             echo "</div>"; 
             echo '</td>';
             echo "</tr>";


          }


          echo "</table>";

?>
```

eliminarlibros.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    {


           $numero = $_GET['numero'];
                    $coneccion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234");
                    mysqli_select_db($coneccion , "biblioteca");

                $consulta = "SELECT count(*) FROM prestados where ReferenciaLibro = '$numero' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $consulta);
                mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if($row[0] == 0)
                {
                    $req = "SELECT count(*) FROM libros where numero = $numero";
                    $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $req);
                    /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */           
                    $Eliminar = "delete from libros where numero = $numero ";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminar);
                    /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */            
                    $Eliminarapa = "delete from apa where numero = $numero ";
                    $resultadoapa = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminarapa);
                    /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */             
                    $Eliminarhardvard = "delete from hardvard where numero = $numero ";
                    $resultadohardvard = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminarhardvard);
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("se elimino el libro correctamente");'
        . 'window.location.href="admin.php";'
                . '</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Este libro esta prestado no se puede eliminar");'
        . 'window.location.href="admin.php";'
                . '</script>';
                }

    }

?>
```

quiero que me pregunte si deseo borrar el libro antes de que lo borre

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Desde donde lanzas la acción de eliminar? Supongo que desde un botón en el cliente o algo así. Creo que es mejor hacer la validación desde el cliente.

Comment: si pero no se como hacerla con javascript, solo entiendo poco de php

Answer (score 6):

Con PHP solamente no vas a poder lograrlo tan facilmente.
Para hacerlo con PHP solamente deberias crear una pagina de confirmacion.
O sea en tu pagina de la lista de registros tendrias varios registros

```
<a href = "pagina_de_confirmar.php/?id=3">Eliminar Registro 3</a>
```

Pagina de confirmacion

```
//en pagina_de_confirmar.php estaria el siguiente codigo
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["id"]))
    {
        ?>
            <p>Realmente desea ELIMINAR este registro?</p>
            <a href = "<?=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]?>">Cancelar</a>
            <br>
            <a href = "eliminar.php/?id=<?=$_GET["id"]?>">Eliminar</a>
        <?php
    }

?>
```

O sea tu boton de eliminar deberia resultar en que te envia a una pagina donde solo habrian dos botones, `Eliminar` o `Regresar`. Luego el boton `Eliminar` te enviaria a la pagina `eliminar.php` quien espera `$_GET["id"]` para eliminar correctamente el registro.

La mejor manera de hacerlo (desde mi punto de vista) es usando JavaScript en el lado del cliente.
Aqui tienes un ejemplo sencillo de como hacerlo

Basicamente lo que hago es darle un evento a la etiqueta `a` para que cuando se produzca un click sobre ella, JS lance una ventana de confirmacion. Esa ventana tiene dos botones, `Ok` que es `true` y `Cancel` que es `false`. Si el usuario diera en `Canelar` = `false`, porque se equivoco y no queria borrar ese registro pues lo que hace el codigo JS es impedir que se realice el evento de la etiqueta `a` que seria enviar una consulta GET, en caso contrario pues todo funciona normal, o sea la consulta se envia.

```
<a onclick = "wantdelete(event)" href = "/confirmed">Elimninar</a>

<script>
function wantdelete(e)
{
    var res = confirm("Quieres elminarlo?");
    if(res == false)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

## Editado

```
    <?php
    //Pagina que va a mostrar todos los registros de tu base de datos
    //Asumiendo que iteras sobre el resultado de una consulta SQL
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch_array())
    {
        ?>
            <a onclick = 'wantdelete(event)' class="ui mini red button" href="eliminarlibros.php?numero=<?=$row['numero']?>" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Eliminar </a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    <script>
        function wantdelete(e)
        {
            var res = confirm('Quieres elminarlo?');
            if(res == false)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```
<?php
    //Esperando a que llegue el numero del ID que quieres eliminar
    //En esta parte quite lo que tenias al final. Revisalo todo cuidadosamnte
    if(isset($_GET['numero']))
    {
        $numero = $_GET['numero'];
        $coneccion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234");
        mysqli_select_db($coneccion , "biblioteca");

        $consulta = "SELECT count(*) FROM prestados where ReferenciaLibro = '$numero' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $consulta);
        mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if($row[0] == 0)
        {
            $req = "SELECT count(*) FROM libros where numero = $numero";
            $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $req);
            /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */           
            $Eliminar = "delete from libros where numero = $numero ";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminar);
            /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */            
            $Eliminarapa = "delete from apa where numero = $numero ";
            $resultadoapa = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminarapa);
            /*$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  */             
            $Eliminarhardvard = "delete from hardvard where numero = $numero ";
            $resultadohardvard = mysqli_query($coneccion, $Eliminarhardvard);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: He editado varias veces para que veas el ejemplo de como seria con PHP solamente y como seria usando JavaScript en una infima porcion. Espero que te sriva de algo. Slds

Comment: Volvi a editar la respuesta. Tienes que prestarle atencion a las comillas simples y las dobles que pueden no estar permitiendo que se ejecute el codigo JS.

Comment: La funcion JS `wantdelete` tiene que ir al final del documento. No puede estar en la iteracion cuando generas la tabla. Asegurate de todo lo que te he dicho y de no generar mas post preguntando cosas. Puedes hacerlo haciendo ediciones en tu pregunta original

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

gracias por su respuesta 
    el botton eliminar lo tengo en una tabla para cada registro , hice la modificacion con javascript que me dijiste 
    echo ' Eliminar';

```
y puse el codigo javascript tal como me lo pusiste 
<script>
function wantdelete(e)
{
    var res = confirm("Quieres elminarlo?");
    if(res === false)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script> 

me sigue eliminando directamente no me pregunta nada

un saludo
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta ?

Comment: Las ediciones a tu pregunta deben ir en tu pub. original ya que este espacio es solo para recibir respuestas, por favor considera eliminar esto, editar tu pregunta y ahi agregar lo que falte

Answer (score 0):

deberías utilizar javascript con el evento onclick para la confirmación

```
<?php

    echo '<a class="ui mini red button" onclick="return preguntar();" 
         href="eliminarlibros.php?numero='.@$row['numero'].'"><i 
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </i>Eliminar</a>';
    echo "</div>"; 

  ?>

  <script>
   function preguntar(){
     eliminar=confirm("¿Deseas eliminar este registro?");
    if (eliminar)
    //Redireccionamos si das a aceptar

     window.location.href="eliminarlibros.php?Id=aca el id del renglón"

    else

    alert('No se ha podido eliminar el registro..')
}
</script>
```